# SharePoint 2013 - Office Application Opening in Read-Only Mode in the Web Application

Tags: 2013

All the Files are opening in the Read-Only Mode across all sites in the Web Application, The files are being Opened in the Client Application. It's not a permission issue because users are able to download and overwrite the same document. so far I have checked the following

1. The Database is not in the Read-Only Mode
2. The Site Collection is not in the Locked State, Checked using PowerShell.
3. All Sites, Including the New One Created, Exhibits the same Behaviour
4. Diskspace plenty on the SQL system
5. ULS Logs/Event Viewer not showing any errors or warnings
6. Confirmed IIS Settings.
7. Tried from Different System using Different Office Applications.

Currently, if the new Web Application is created, This behavior is no longer happening within the same SharePoint farm, so we have narrowed down the issue to the Web Application. The only issue is I want to know if we can resolve it without having the need to move it to the new web application.

Comment: Not referring to Office Web Apps, but Desktop Apps such as Word, Excel. I used the word Web Application because it's happening across all sites. The User Licensing is still disabled. I have ported the content database to the new application and everything seems to be working in there. The Claims Authentication Type is set to Windows Authentication, with Integrated Windows Authentication NTLM.

Comment: I am not sure if there is any correlation but KB4465659 was installed prior to the issue being reported

Answer (score 1):

This happens if you enable user licensing in SP Server without setting the licenses. Could this be the case?

To enable licensing:

```
Enable-SPUserLicensing
```

Then for NTLM-enabled web applications:

```
$groupName = "ENGINEERER\OfficeWebAppsEnabledUsers"
$map = New-SPUserLicenseMapping -SecurityGroup $groupName -License OfficeWebAppsEdit
Add-SPUserLicenseMapping -Mapping $map
$map = New-SPUserLicenseMapping -SecurityGroup $groupName -License Standard
Add-SPUserLicenseMapping -Mapping $map
```

And for Claims-enabled web applications:

```
$claimString = New-SPClaimsPrincipal -EncodedClaim "c:0-.t|adfs|ENINEERER\OfficeWebAppsEnabledUsers"
$map = New-SPUserLicenseMapping -Claim $claimString -License OfficeWebAppsEdit
Add-SPUserLicenseMapping -Mapping $map
$map = New-SPUserLicenseMapping -Claim $claimString -License Standard
Add-SPUserLicenseMapping -Mapping $map
```

Comment: if User Licensing enabled , then how come other web application is working fine.. ( just for clarification )

Comment: There is no mention of Office Web Apps Server in the question, so this answer does not apply to it.

Comment: @THIVAGARSEGAR: It might be because the new web application doen't receive updates that "Enable-SPUserLicensing" triggered - because it was created after the CMDlet was executed. But I'm not sure.

Comment: @LukasNespor: The title confuses me.. I thought with "Read-Only Mode in the Web Application" is Office Online Server meant.

Comment: Office Web App is not involved. The documents are opening on the users desktops  The Get-SPUserLicensing returns false. The files are editable on the new web applications onto which the content database was exported. It's definitely an authentication issue cannot figure out if it's something in IIS or SharePoint.